# keras - softmax top N - loss function

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am having trouble how to use keras to fit my scenario. In my output layer, it would output the probabilities of each item. I would like to take the top N items (i.e. with highest probability) and see if they are a subset of the truth (which has a set of items). I have to compile the negative log likelihood for this scenario. May I ask how may I go about doing that?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

`

```
nn = Sequential()
 nn.add(Dense(self.num_hidden_units, input_dim = input_num, init="uniform"))
 nn.add(Activation('tanh'))
 nn.add(Dense(self.num_items, init="uniform"))
 nn.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

`

Comment: Is it a multi-label, or multi-class scenario? In other words, are your labels are mutually exclusive?

Comment: The output is the probabilities of each item occurring, you can say each class. But they are not mutually exclusive as I mentioned I would like to take the top N in the output and see if they are a subset of the truth set. But I am not sure how do I apply negative log likelihood in this case. I can't use categorical cross entropy since I am not predicting one class from multiclasses. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are in the [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) regime. The common objective function in this case is a binary cross entropy loss, above an activation of a `sigmoid`.

Note that you should replace the softmax activation with a sigmoid, since in the your case the probabilities don't have to sum to 1

A usage example for applying the loss in keras:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
```

Comment: I thought binary crossentropy is for binary classification. So when it's multi-label classification, we use binary crossentropy too?

Also, why sigmoid instead of softmax? I mean does it make a difference?

Comment: In multilabel, you like to predict whether a class exists or not, hence the binary. Since several classes can exist concurrently, you need to use sigmoid instead of softmax, because softmax is suited for the case the classes are mutually exclusive. For example. if an image has a bird and a dog, an ideal sigmoid classifier will result in output_dog=1, output_bird=1, all other outputs=0, while with softmax the closest you can get is output_dog=0.5, output_bird=0.5, all other outputs=0

Comment: Oh....I completely get what you mean. What if they are mutually exclusive? then what should the loss be?

PS I am actually trying to implement this paper - http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1441/recsys2015_poster15.pdf , on next basket recommendation as a practice since its structure is rather simple. But I just don't quite get how should I use negative log likelihood with keras

Comment: If they are mutually exclusive, then you'd rather use softmax output activation, with a categorical cross entropy loss

Comment: but my y_true would be something like a vector of length = total number of items, the value would be 1  if that item is present, otherwise 0, because I don't have the truth probability. If I need softmax to get items of top probability, is it a good idea to add extra processing, which I pick the items with highest probabilities, they would be 1 in the resultant vector, so it's comparable to y truth?

Thanks a lot and sorry for all the followup questions